# Using value of automatically generated column for follow-on query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query where I am adding two user's to a 'group'. So I have a group table with columns -

```
group_id (AUTO_INCREMENT = true)
user_id
```

So I insert the first user to the group with

```
INSERT INTO group (user_id) VALUES (user_1);
```

which automatically creates a group_id. I want to add the second user to the table with this same group_id. So is there a way to do it all in one call to the database? Im looking for something like the following query string -

```
"INSERT INTO group (user_id) VALUES (user_1); 
group_id = getLastInsertedKey();
INSERT INTO group (user_id) VALUES (user_2);"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you could try:

```
INSERT INTO `group` (user_id) 
    VALUES (user_1);
INSERT INTO `group` (user_id, group_id) 
    VALUES (
        (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()) a, 
        user_2);
```

The idea is to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to retrieve last auto-generated value and use it in the next query.
As I've already told you, I'm not sure if it works, but the idea should be good enough for you.

Comment: Actually it works in phpmyadmin but it is not working when I send the exact same query using jdbc connector in java.

Comment: Are you sure you can send multiple queries with jdbc connector? I've never used it, so I cannot help you. Anyway remember that the one I wrote is not ONE query, but they are TWO queries: try to execute them separately with jdbc and let me know if it works...